# Excel AutoPostBack issue

Tags: excel, vba

I put AutoPostBack= True in excel VBA code, while changing value of cell it does not update result.

```
Private Sub Sheet1()
AutoPostBack = True

If (Cells(2, 1).Value = "---") And (Cells(1, 2).Value = 0) Then
Cells(2, 2).Value = 0
Else
Cells(2, 2).Value = "   "
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect `AutoPostBack` should do. There is no AutoPostBack Property in VBA. That is an ASP.NET issue. In VBA it is just a normal variable. You could also write `Humpfdidumpfdi=True`.

Comment: I want when in put any value other than 0 in Cell(1,2), the value in cells(2,2) will be updated immediately

Answer (score 0):

In VBA editor open the code for the worksheet you want to work on (double click it in project explorer). Then select in the dropdown boxes on the top of the editor window `Worksheet` and `SelectionChange`. Put your code into the created `Worksheet_SelectionChange` function instead of your `Sheet1` function. This is the function which is executed automatically on every change on your worksheet.

Alternatively you can make your `Sheet1` function public and call it from the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

And forget the `AutoPostBack`